# form not submiting with target option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image-uploading, ajaxform

I have an issue with my javascript upload code.
It works ok in localhost but not in the server.

HTML :

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
        Elija la imagen <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg"/>
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function(){           
        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="images/loader2.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target:'#preview'}).submit();
        //$( "#imageform" ).submit();
    });
});
```

if I change $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target:'#preview'}).submit(); for $("#imageform").submit(); it works fine, but i need the image to be loaded in the preview div tag.

Thanks !

Comment: What exactly does not work..?

Comment: I think it is expecting success handler $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
target:'#preview', success: function() {/*something on success*/} }).submit()

Comment: Well ... It seems like there is no response from the action page. After browsing the file, the function loads the gif animation into #preview div and that´s all. The same code works just fine in my local server

Comment: Just added succes handler and still not works. alert('1') just before submit() pops up but alert('2') after the call does not. In ajaximage.php echo '3' just at the beging does not shows up in the target div. Without ajaxForm({target:'#preview'}), submit triggers fine, but redirects me to the action php (echo shown and code executed fine). Seems that the problem is "ajaxForm({target:'#preview'})"